# Android - Add menu item programmatically with XML Template

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I have the following menu.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_one"
          android:title="Item One"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_build_black"
          android:checkable="true"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_two"
          android:title="Item Two"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_balance_black"
          android:checkable="true"/>

</menu>
```

I would like to add some menu items programmatically, and have successfully done so doing the following.

```
public class NavDrawer extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    myMenu.add(0, 100, 0, "Item Three").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_some_icon).setCheckable(true);
    myMenu.add(0, 101, 0, "Item Four").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_some_icon).setCheckable(true);

...
```

The issue is I have to call several methods to set the attributes as I would like them. It would be ideal if instead I could use an XML template to define all the items.

The file might look like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<item android:id="@+id/nav_item_template"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_some_icon"
      android:checkable="true"/>
```

And adding menu items might be done as such.

```
myMenu.add(0, 101, 0, R.id.nav_item_template).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_some_icon).setCheckable(true);
```

Is there any such feature or ability in the Android SDK?

P.S. This menu belongs to a NavigationView built for a DrawerLayout.

Comment: which method are you doing this in:
`onCreateOptionsMenu` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu`

Comment: @MidasLefko My activity `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`. The menu belongs to the NavigationView.

Comment: would this help: 
`<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
...
app:menu="@menu/menu"/>`

Comment: @MidasLefko That's what I am currently using.

Comment: I guess I dont understand your question... Sorry

Comment: @MidasLefko I would like a why to add menu items in code, but have a template for the item in the XML file as you would if it was a static menu items.